# Spring request hangs when HttpServletResponse/HttpServletRequest are added as method parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Following the example provided by spring.io for [creating a simple REST service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), I run into a strange issue.

If I make a request to `localhost:8080/greeting` the greeting route is called and I receive the expected response:

```
{"id":1, "content":"Hello, World!"}
```

If I add a route "/test" and then make an HTTP GET request to `localhost:8080/test` I get the expected response:

```
I'm a teapot
```

The problem arises when I do one of two things. Firstly, if I add HttpServletResponse or HttpServletRequest as a parameter to the test route and make an HTTP GET request to `localhost:8080/test`, the request hangs, the route is not called/executed, and maybe but not always the following is returned:

```
BODY: OK STATUS CODE: UNKNOWN 43
```

The second case is when I try to overcome this by using the @Autowire annotation. If I remove the HttpServletResponse/HttpServletRequest method parameters and instead autowire them in as class members, I get the same behavior.

If I make a request to any other invalid/undefined route e.g. HTTP GET `localhost:8080/undefinedroute` I receive the expected 404.

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    //@Autowired
    //HttpServletRequest request;

    //@Autowired
    //HttpServletResponse response;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String index() {
       return HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.getReasonPhrase();
    }

    //@RequestMapping("/test")
    //public String index(HttpServletResponse response) {
       //response.setStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.ordinal());
       //return HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.getReasonPhrase();
    //}

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Comment: `BODY: OK STATUS CODE: UNKNOWN 43` doesn't look like it's come from the Boot app. Are you accessing it directly or is it behind a proxy, load balancer, etc?

Comment: That is just from my rest client advanced rest in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot autowire HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse, because these objects are created when the server receives and handles an HTTP request. They are not beans in the Spring application context.

---

The status code of your response is 43 (unknown) because of this line:

```
response.setStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.ordinal()); // status 43?
```

[`ordinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) gives you the position of enum declaration, not the value of the status code. `I_AM_A_TEAPOT` is the 43rd enum declared in HttpStatus. The request hangs because 43 is an invalid status code and your browser does not know how to deal with it. You should use:

```
response.setStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.value()); // status 418
```